# Implicit Differentiation - Second Order

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, real-numbers

There is no trouble when I have to differentiate a function  $f(x,y)$ where $y=g(x)$ using Implicit Function Theorem. It's easy to get $g_{xx}$ and $g_{yy}$. For instance, the formula for $g_{xx}=-\frac{f_{xx}F_y^2-(F_{xy}+F_{yx})F_xF_y+F_{yy}F_x^2}{F_y^3}$ knowing that $g'(x)=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}$ whenever $F_y\neq{0}$.

Now, i'm in the situation $z+x+(y+z)^4=0$ where it defines an implicit function $z=f(x,y)$.

I got $f_x$ and $f_y$ using the theorem. However, I can't get $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ from there. I know I shoud apply the chain rule but I get lost whenever trying to get a "general formula" for them.

Comment: Well there are probably some shortcut formulas, but why not just use the basic rules of implicit differentiation?  So for instance $z_x+1+4(y+z)^3z_x=0$, and so on?

Comment: Nice idea, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $F(x,y,z(x,y))=0$,
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F=F_x+F_zz_x=0 \implies z_x=-\frac{F_x}{F_z}\\
&\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}F=F_{xx}+F_{xz}z_x+z_x(F_{zx}+F_{zz}z_x)+F_z z_{xx}=0
\end{align}
Plugging in $z_x$ and rearranging, it should be clear how to solve for $z_{xx}$. A similar method holds for $y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just get confused doing these kind of problems. I can clearly see it now.